# Laravel 5.5 Supplementing Resource Controllers example

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I have difficults to create a supplementing Resource in a controller laravel and insert it in the web.php for the routing.

I would to implement a search functions, in an Articles controller .Beyond the authomatic generated function like (index, show...) i have created another one:

`public function search($title){
      $articles = Article::findOrFail($title);
        return $articles;
      }`

And I have added it in the web.php for the routing:

```
Route::resource('articles/{title}', 'ArticleController@search');
```

When I try to test this search, it doesn't work. All the implicit controller go well, I have problem only with this selfmade function.

How can I solve this issue?

thanks

Comment: Resource routes have to point to an (entire) resource controller, implementing the functions described in the docs. This way you try to point to 1 function `search`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another route before `resource` one to make it work:

```
Route::get('articles/{title}', 'ArticleController@search');
```

You also want to change the query if you want to find an article by it's slug, for example:

```
$article = User::where('slug', $title)->first();
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Two mistake: the get instead resource in the route and the query! Thanks

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594340/how-can-i-implement-resource-controllers-if-i-use-many-get-on-the-laravel